# Create a clickable item like button with a particuliar view inside

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm starting in android but I'm working on a project that asks me to do the same thing as the pictures below. However I don't know how to analyze this view to be able to produce something similar.
From what I see in the activity I have a "button" and when I click on it, the elements present in the "button" change. Could someone explain to me how to cut out the view and the elements to do the same thing? Thank you in advance for your answer.

Pictures :

[based view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yowZA.png)

[view after click on "button"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sdLR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Miina Neko Use card view inside cardview use a linear layout (or anyother layout you like) inside cardview use below code i made a layout for you

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_5sdp"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/_5sdp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/refresh_btn"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="arrrarrr-raaar"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_3sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_3sdp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/refresh_btn"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_10sdp" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/refresh_btn"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_10sdp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:indeterminateDrawable="@android:drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

NOTE: "@dimen/_sdp" is a library i am sharing link and chage your drawable accrouding to your choice and make ids and in java or kotlin change then programmatically when clicked or any action performed like in second picture hope answer your question..
SDP library link https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Comment: Can I create the 10 layouts from an xml for the xml of the activity? For example when we make a listView we make an example layout and give it to the listView to create them.

Comment: i have no idea what you want to achive but you can create multiple views through java but through xml i dont think it is possible 
can you please elaborate what are you trying to do?

Comment: That's ok, thanks! I will use a RecyclerView with cardView like you showed me.

Comment: if answer is helpful please mark it correct thanks

Answer (score 1):

I gonna give you a rough idea..

its not a button its a layout containing 2 textviews, 2 imageviews and one seekbar and i will suggest you to use a linearlayout.add a clicklistner on it.

to change the elements after clicking on layout you have to get the references of its elements textview etc as mentioned and change them by yourself. ex- seekbar.setprogress(30) approximately as your picture after click.

xml..

```
Linearlayout
         textview
          imageview and textview 
          imageview
         seekbar
    \Linearlayout
```

Comment: Ok ! Thank you.  So I need to have 10 layout like that in the xml ?